# how to attach an event listener using jQuery map v3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, jquery-ui-map

i am trying to load more markers when the map is dragged and i'm not sure how to get the current bounds.

```
var map = $('#map');
map.gmap().bind('init', function(evt, map) {
    $(map).dragend(function(){
        console.log('a');
    });
});
```

i need to somehow get the current bounds inside the `dragend` callback and load more markers..

notice that i am using `jQuery UI Map v3` and not `Google Maps Api v3` witch is a bit different in the way it calls different methods

anyone has any ideas, i can't find this in the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/wiki/jquery_ui_map_v_3_api)?

thanks

Comment: any errors you see  ?

Comment: no errors, i just don't know how to proceed further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **variant #1** (using the `addEventListener`-method of the plugin)

  ```
      $(function() { 
        $('#map_canvas')
          .gmap()
            .bind('init', function(evt, map) {
                $(map)
                  .addEventListener('dragend',function(){
                                      console.log('a');
                                    });
                  });
      });
  ```
- **variant #2**(using the `addEventListener`-method of the google-Maps-API)

  ```
  $(function() { 
    $('#map_canvas')
      .gmap()
        .bind('init', function(evt, map) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragend',function(){
                                  console.log('b');
                                });
              });
  });
  ```